# What is a good way to display a spinner at the bottom of a tableview when a user scrolls, but the tableview cells load slowly?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays some content. When the user scrolls upward, the cells below don't always load immediately. This creates an area of white space at the bottom of the table. I would like to display a spinner in the white space and have it disappear when the content is done loading, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. What is a good way to implement something like this in swift?

I am new to coding and iOS, please forgive me if the question is vague or the answer is obvious.

**Sample Screenshot :**

[image: sample image for desired behavior]

Comment: put activatity indicator in tablviewfooterview.

Comment: I had no idea that this existed! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's helpful for you..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
    if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
        // print("this is the last cell")
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .red)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))

        self.tableview.tableFooterView = spinner
        self.tableview.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

`tableFooterView` should be hide when data load.
when above function isn't work so you can prefer this [link.](https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll)

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback Ravi. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Set UIActivityIndicatorView as a UITableView's footerView in viewDidLoad.

```
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44);

self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.indicator;
```

When the tableview is about to display the last row of cells and you have more data to load, then load more data.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == self.arrList.count-1 && self.hasMoreList == YES) {
        [self loadData];
    }
}
```

Just start animating indicator before loading and stop animating it after loading data.

```
- (void)loadData {

    [self.indicator startAnimating];

    // load data and set hasMoreData here ... 

    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: this is a much better solution. Spoofing a cell feels dirty to me.